# Обновление окна в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Решил создать телефонный справочник с помощью tkinter, который должен работать следующим образом:

1. На экран выводится весть список лиц, который берется из созданного файла "mydatabase.db" базы данных SQLite;
2. При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить" - открывается второе вспомогательное окно, в котором вводятся данные нового лица (район, имя, телефон, должность). После чего в указанном окне нажимается ещё одна кнопка "Добавить", которая добавляет в файл базы данных новое лицо и закрывает вспомогательное окно.
3. После чего я попадаю в главное окно программы, в котором в конец списка должно добавиться новое лицо, но этого не происходит (остается прежний список лиц). Чтобы увидеть добавленное лицо нужно перезапустить программу (закрыть и заново запустить).

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добиться отображения измененного (дополненного) списка контактов?**
(заранее огромное спасибо)

Программа состоит из нескольких модулей.

1. appg.py (главный)
2. другие модули
3. tab_telephone.py (подключается к главному модулю)

**appg.py**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

from tab_appg import Appg
from tab_percent_positive import PercentPositive
from tab_percent import Percent
# ИМПОРТИРУЕМ МОДУЛЬ С НАШЕЙ ТЕЛЕФОННОЙ КНИГОЙ
from tab_telephone import Telephone


class MainInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.window.title('Название')
        self.window.geometry("500x500")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.window['padx'] = 10
        self.window['pady'] = 10

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.window, width=475, height=450)

        a_tab = Appg(self.notebook)
        b_tab = PercentPositive(self.notebook)
        c_tab = Percent(self.notebook)
        d_tab = Telephone(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(a_tab, text="  АППГ  ")
        self.notebook.add(b_tab, text="  Раскываемость  ")
        self.notebook.add(c_tab, text="  АППГ от процента  ")
        self.notebook.add(d_tab, text="  Телефонный справочник  ")

        self.notebook.grid(row=1, column=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    program = MainInterface()
    program.window.mainloop()
```

**tab_telephone.py**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
import os.path


class Telephone(tkinter.Frame):
    """Телефонный справочник"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.exist_database()
        self.init_ui()

    def exist_database(self):
        """Проверка существования базы данных. Если БД не существует - создает БД"""
        self.file_path = 'mydatabase.db'

        if not os.path.exists(self.file_path):
            conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            # Создание таблицы
            cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE phone_book
                          (area text, name text, phone text, position text)
                           """)
        else:
            print('База данных уже создана')

    def select_all_from_database(self):
        """ Выводит на экран все контакты из БД """
        conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        sql = "SELECT * FROM phone_book"
        result = cursor.execute(sql)
        result2 = cursor.fetchall()
        return result2

    def init_ui(self):
        """Создание телефонной книги"""
        self.text = tkinter.Text(self, width=55, height=22)
        for i in self.select_all_from_database():
            self.text.insert(tkinter.INSERT, f'РАЙОН:\t{i[0]}\nФИО:\t{i[1]}\nТЕЛ:\t{i[2]}\nДОЛЖН:\t{i[3]}' + '\n' + '-------------------------------------------------------' + '\n')
        self.text.configure(state='disabled')

        # создаем "скроллер" (ползунок прокрутки), который устанавливается comand=text.yview, где y - ось.
        self.scroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(self, command=self.text.yview)
        # RIGHT - ползунок справа, Y - по оси Y.
        self.scroll.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
        # расположение элемента <TEXT>, например side=tkinter.LEFT
        self.text.place(x=5, y=40)
        self.text.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)

        ##### МЕНЮ ПОИСКА #####
        self.label_search = tkinter.Label(self, text='Введите фамилию для поиска: ')
        # entry - (анг. вход) - поле для ввода данных пользователем
        self.entry_search = tkinter.Entry(self, width=30)
        # устанавливаем расположение (place, анг. место) для элементов
        self.label_search.place(x=5, y=9)
        self.entry_search.place(x=200, y=9)

        ##### КНОПКИ #####
        # Кнопка поиска
        self.search = tkinter.Button(self, text='Найти', command=self.search_def)
        # упаковываем созданные элементы (side - сторона).
        self.search.place(x=400, y=5)
        # Кнопка добавления нового контакта
        self.add_new_window = tkinter.Button(self, text='Добавить', command=self.create_new_window)
        self.add_new_window.place(x=10, y=420)

  
    def search_def(self):
        """ поиск контакта по справочнику """
        pass

    def create_new_window(self):
        """Выполняется при нажатии кнопки "Добавить" для открытия нового окна, для добавления нового контакта """
        self.new_window = tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.new_window.geometry("600x170")
        
        # принимаем значение для поля в таблице базы данных "Район"
        self.area = tkinter.StringVar()
        label_add_area = tkinter.Label(self.new_window, text='Введите район или место работы: ')
        entry_add_area = tkinter.Entry(self.new_window, width=55, textvariable=self.area)
        label_add_area.place(x=5, y=10)
        entry_add_area.place(x=250, y=10)

        # принимаем значение для поля в таблице базы данных "Имя"    
        self.name = tkinter.StringVar()
        label_add_name = tkinter.Label(self.new_window, text='Введите ФИО: ')
        entry_add_name = tkinter.Entry(self.new_window, width=55, textvariable=self.name)
        label_add_name.place(x=5, y=40)
        entry_add_name.place(x=250, y=40)

        # принимаем значение для поля в таблице базы данных "Телефон"
        self.phone = tkinter.StringVar()
        label_add_phone = tkinter.Label(self.new_window, text='Введите номер(а) телефона: ')
        entry_add_phone = tkinter.Entry(self.new_window, width=55, textvariable=self.phone)
        label_add_phone.place(x=5, y=70)
        entry_add_phone.place(x=250, y=70)

        # принимаем значение для поля в таблице базы данных "Должность"
        self.position = tkinter.StringVar()
        label_add_position = tkinter.Label(self.new_window, text='Введите должность или описание: ')
        entry_add_position = tkinter.Entry(self.new_window, width=55, textvariable=self.position)
        label_add_position.place(x=5, y=100)
        entry_add_position.place(x=250, y=100)

        ##### КНОПКИ #####
        button_add_member = tkinter.Button(self.new_window, text='Добавить', command=self.insert_to_database)
        button_add_member.place(x=5, y=130)

        self.new_window.mainloop()


    def insert_to_database(self):
        """Вносим новые контакты телефонной книги"""
        conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        area = self.area.get()
        name = self.name.get()
        phone = self.phone.get()
        position = self.position.get()

        member = [(area, name, phone, position)]

        cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO phone_book VALUES (?,?,?,?)", member)
        # Сохраняем изменения
        conn.commit()
        # Уничтожаем окно для добавления контактов и попадаем в главное окно
        self.new_window.destroy()
```

**Остальные модули программы: (не относятся к вопросу, но для запуска без правок возможно пригодятся).**

**tab_percent.py**

```
import tkinter

class Percent(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        ##### ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ ТЕКУЩЕГО ГОДА #####
        # лейбл для отображения поля "текущего (анг. current) год"
        self.label_current_year = tkinter.Label(self, text='Введите значение текущего года: ')
        # entry - (анг. вход) - поле для ввода данных пользователем
        self.entry_current_year = tkinter.Entry(self, width=10)
        # устанавливаем расположение (place, анг. место) для элементов
        self.label_current_year.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
        self.entry_current_year.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.1)

        ##### ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ ПРОШЛОГО ГОДА #####
        self.label_last_year_percent = tkinter.Label(self, text='Введите процент прошлого года: ')
        self.entry_last_year_percent = tkinter.Entry(self, width=10)
        # устанавливаем расположение (place, анг. место) для элементов
        self.label_last_year_percent.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2)
        self.entry_last_year_percent.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.2)

        ##### ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ РАСЧЕТА #####
        self.label_calculation = tkinter.Label(self, text='Результат: ')
        # StringVar - связан с элементом lable и в его поле textvariable вносит получившее значение
        # из переменной calculation.
        self.calculation = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.label_calculation_result = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.calculation)
        # упаковываем созданные элементы (side - сторона).
        self.label_calculation.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3)
        self.label_calculation_result.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.3)

        ##### КНОПКИ #####
        self.button_calculation = tkinter.Button(self, text='Рассчитать', command=self.calculation_def)

        # упаковываем созданные элементы (side - сторона).
        self.button_calculation.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.4)

    def calculation_def(self):
        # получаем данные из полей enty, куда пользоватеь ввоил свои данные, при помощи метода get
        self.current_year = int(self.entry_current_year.get())
        self.last_year_persent = float(self.entry_last_year_percent.get())
        # вычисляем количество от процента, связанного с прошлым годом

        self.result_persent = 100 + self.last_year_persent
        self.result_sum = self.current_year * 100 / self.result_persent
        # разница
        self.difference = self.current_year - self.result_sum
        self.appg = round(self.current_year - self.difference)

        # обновляем элемент label_calculation_result в рамке рачета, сохранив значение calculation_result в
        # объект StingVar, на который ссылается переменная calculation
        self.calculation.set(self.appg)
```

**tab_appg.py**

```
import tkinter

class Appg(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        """ Создаем виджет расчета АППГ для текущего окна"""
        ##### ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ ТЕКУЩЕГО ГОДА #####
        # лейбл для отображения поля "текущий (анг. current) год"
        self.label_current_year = tkinter.Label(self, text='Введите значение текущего года: ')
        # entry - (анг. вход) - поле для ввода данных пользователем
        self.entry_current_year = tkinter.Entry(self, width=10)
        # устанавливаем расположение (place, анг. место) для элементов
        self.label_current_year.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
        self.entry_current_year.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.1)

        ##### ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ ПРОШЛОГО ГОДА #####
        self.label_last_year = tkinter.Label(self, text='Введите значение прошлого года: ')
        self.entry_last_year = tkinter.Entry(self, width=10)
        # устанавливаем расположение (place, анг. место) для элементов
        self.label_last_year.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2)
        self.entry_last_year.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.2)

        ##### ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ РАСЧЕТА #####
        self.label_calculation = tkinter.Label(self, text='Результат: ')
        # StringVar - связан с элементом lable и в его поле textvariable вносит получившее значение
        # из переменной calculation.
        self.calculation = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.label_calculation_result = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.calculation)
        # упаковываем созданные элементы (side - сторона).
        self.label_calculation.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3)
        self.label_calculation_result.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.3)

        ##### КНОПКИ #####
        self.button_calculation = tkinter.Button(self, text='Рассчитать', command=self.calculation_def)

        # упаковываем созданные элементы (side - сторона).
        self.button_calculation.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.4)


    def calculation_def(self):
        # получаем данные из полей enty, куда пользоватеь ввоил свои данные, при помощи метода get
        self.current_year = int(self.entry_current_year.get())
        self.last_year = int(self.entry_last_year.get())
        # вычисляем АППГ
        self.calculation_result = str(round(((self.current_year - self.last_year) / self.last_year) * 100, 1)) + "%"
        # обновляем элемент label_calculation_result в рамке рачета, сохранив значение calculation_result в
        # объект StingVar, на который ссылается переменная calculation
        self.calculation.set(self.calculation_result)
```

**tab_percent_positive.py**

```
import tkinter

class PercentPositive(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.label_crime_solved = tkinter.Label(self, text='Введите количество : ')
        # entry - (анг. вход) - поле для ввода данных пользователем
        self.entry_crime_solved = tkinter.Entry(self, width=10)
        # устанавливаем расположение (place, анг. место) для элементов
        self.label_crime_solved.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
        self.entry_crime_solved.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.1)

        self.label_suspended_crime = tkinter.Label(self, text='Введите количество: ')
        self.entry_suspended_crime = tkinter.Entry(self, width=10)
        # устанавливаем расположение (place, анг. место) для элементов
        self.label_suspended_crime.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2)
        self.entry_suspended_crime.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.2)

        ##### ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ РАСЧЕТА #####
        self.label_calculation = tkinter.Label(self, text='Результат: ')
        # StringVar - связан с элементом lable и в его поле textvariable вносит получившее значение
        # из переменной calculation.
        self.calculation = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.label_calculation_result = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.calculation)
        # упаковываем созданные элементы (side - сторона).
        self.label_calculation.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3)
        self.label_calculation_result.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.3)

        ##### КНОПКИ #####
        self.button_calculation = tkinter.Button(self, text='Рассчитать', command=self.calculation_def)

        # упаковываем созданные элементы (side - сторона).
        self.button_calculation.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.4)

    def calculation_def(self):
        # получаем данные из полей enty, куда пользоватеь ввоил свои данные, при помощи метода get
        self.quantity_crime_solved = int(self.entry_crime_solved.get())
        self.quantity_suspended_crime = int(self.entry_suspended_crime.get())
        # вычисляем АППГ
        self.calculation_result = str(round(
            self.quantity_crime_solved / (self.quantity_crime_solved + self.quantity_suspended_crime) * 100, 1)) + "%"
        # обновляем элемент label_calculation_result в рамке рачета, сохранив значение calculation_result в
        # объект StingVar, на который ссылается переменная calculation
        self.calculation.set(self.calculation_result)
```

Comment: Решил проблему при помощи метода destroy(), который применил к элементам tkinter.Text и tkinter.Scrollbar. При вызове дополнительного окна для добавления нового пользователя, при нажатии на кнопку "добавить" в базу данных вписываются новые данные и вызывается метод destroy() для следующих элементов
self.text.destroy()
self.scroll.destroy()

После чего вызывается ранее созданный метод init_ui(), который заново создает элемент tkinter.text и tkinter.Scrollbar и заполняет его данными из базы данных. 
Но, как-то не элегантно выглядит решение. Возможно ли иначе решить проблему?

Comment: Попробуй собрать все виджеты в Frame и проделать эту операцию с ним

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй обновлять окно с помощью метода `.update()`